# C# streamreader read data multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I have this code:

```
  using (StreamReader csvreader = new StreamReader(fuFiles.FileContent))
            {
                while (!csvreader.EndOfStream)
                {
                  //reading data
                }
            }
```

I'm using this in two different functions. 
In the first function the EndOfStream value is false and the data can be read properly. 
In the second function this same kind of code says that EndOfStream is true and I'm not able to read data. I'm creating streamreader objects independently.

### Edit

I'm adding one more line of explanation, when I'm commenting the first method then I'm able to read the data in the second method.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the file exist or have content in the second method?

Comment: What's are the types of `fuFiles` and `fuFiles.FileContent`?

Comment: Yes it does, first method checks only some special chars and if they exist it returns false before actually reading and saving the data. When I'm commenting out the first method, I'm able to get the data in the second method.

Comment: What kind of thing is `fuFiles.FileContent` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman csv file

Comment: No, is it a `string` or  a `stream` ? Please read [ask].

Comment: It's a stream which comes from uploaded csv file, it's not a string @HenkHolterman

Comment: Hi Laziale. I am a volunteer editor here, and I notice that you regularly sign your posts. I have removed that from many of your posts, and I believe I have commented to you in the past about it. Would you desist from adding this? I can probably find a _Meta_ reference about it, if you are not certain about the guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

There are only two constructors for StreamReader that take one parameter. Since "FileContent" is probably not a string, it must be a Stream of some kind. The first time it is read from it is left at the end. Therefore you must either reset it to the beginning (if it allows that), make a copy before reading, or get a new one created.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the variable names in the code you provided, it looks like you're passing the contents of a file to the `StreamReader` constructor. However, that [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_) takes the path to the file to read - not the contents of the file.

You can use the [`StringReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader?view=netframework-4.8) class to use a stream to read from a string, if that is what you want to do.

Comment: first of all thx for your reply. I'm able to read the data when I'm commenting out the first method which checks for special chars.

Comment: @Laziale based on the comments on the question, `FileContent` is a stream. Streams typically are only read once. So the second time the function is called the stream is already at the end. This means that @Mike's answer is correct.